# List all users and their roles - runs too slow

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I am using this query to list out all users and their parent roles using Postgres 12.8 running on RDS.

```
select distinct on (user_role_name) pgr.oid as user_role_id, pgr.rolname as user_role_name, pgr.rolcanlogin, pgr.rolvaliduntil, 
ARRAY(SELECT b.rolname
FROM pg_catalog.pg_auth_members m
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_roles b ON (m.roleid = b.oid)
WHERE m.member = pgr.oid) as "parent_role_names"
from pg_roles pgr inner join pg_auth_members pgam on pgr.oid=pgam.member inner join pg_roles pgr2 on pgam.roleid=pgr2.oid
```

The issue is that this is taking 39 seconds to return 114 users. The culprit, based on some experiments, is the ARRAY select statement.

What can I do to optimize it?

Here's the query plan - EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS):

```
                                                                                                                                                              |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Unique  (cost=84949.19..84950.26 rows=137 width=109) (actual time=38471.196..38471.342 rows=114 loops=1)                                                                  |
  Buffers: shared hit=13114723                                                                                                                                            |
  ->  Sort  (cost=84949.19..84949.72 rows=214 width=109) (actual time=38471.195..38471.296 rows=214 loops=1)                                                              |
        Sort Key: pg_authid.rolname                                                                                                                                       |
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 83kB                                                                                                                              |
        Buffers: shared hit=13114723                                                                                                                                      |
        ->  Gather  (cost=1102.79..84940.90 rows=214 width=109) (actual time=0.489..38469.169 rows=214 loops=1)                                                           |
              Workers Planned: 2                                                                                                                                          |
              Workers Launched: 2                                                                                                                                         |
              Buffers: shared hit=13114723                                                                                                                                |
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=102.79..16035.23 rows=89 width=77) (actual time=21.432..8514.607 rows=71 loops=3)                                                    |
                    Buffers: shared hit=5502039                                                                                                                           |
                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=51.39..11108.06 rows=89 width=81) (actual time=21.398..1451.972 rows=71 loops=3)                                               |
                          Buffers: shared hit=2167871                                                                                                                     |
                          ->  Parallel Seq Scan on pg_auth_members pgam  (cost=0.00..6180.89 rows=89 width=8) (actual time=13.223..17.476 rows=71 loops=3)                |
                                Buffers: shared hit=6180                                                                                                                  |
                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on pg_authid  (cost=51.39..55.41 rows=1 width=77) (actual time=19.949..19.949 rows=1 loops=214)                            |
                                Recheck Cond: (oid = pgam.member)                                                                                                         |
                                Heap Blocks: exact=97                                                                                                                     |
                                Buffers: shared hit=2161691                                                                                                               |
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on pg_authid_oid_index  (cost=0.00..51.39 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=2.619..2.619 rows=10067 loops=214)           |
                                      Index Cond: (oid = pgam.member)                                                                                                     |
                                      Buffers: shared hit=7247                                                                                                            |
                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on pg_authid pg_authid_1  (cost=51.39..55.41 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=98.826..98.826 rows=1 loops=214)                       |
                          Recheck Cond: (oid = pgam.roleid)                                                                                                               |
                          Heap Blocks: exact=97                                                                                                                           |
                          Buffers: shared hit=3334168                                                                                                                     |
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on pg_authid_oid_index  (cost=0.00..51.39 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=5.813..5.813 rows=15534 loops=214)                 |
                                Index Cond: (oid = pgam.roleid)                                                                                                           |
                                Buffers: shared hit=9954                                                                                                                  |
              SubPlan 1                                                                                                                                                   |
                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=208.81..317.22 rows=2 width=64) (actual time=4.807..169.007 rows=2 loops=214)                                                      |
                      Buffers: shared hit=7612684                                                                                                                         |
                      ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on pg_auth_members m  (cost=116.41..124.33 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=2.101..10.706 rows=2 loops=214)                        |
                            Recheck Cond: (member = pg_authid.oid)                                                                                                        |
                            Heap Blocks: exact=402                                                                                                                        |
                            Buffers: shared hit=979094                                                                                                                    |
                            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on pg_auth_members_member_role_index  (cost=0.00..116.41 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=1.192..1.192 rows=10157 loops=214)|
                                  Index Cond: (member = pg_authid.oid)                                                                                                    |
                                  Buffers: shared hit=7515                                                                                                                |
                      ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on pg_authid pg_authid_2  (cost=92.40..96.42 rows=1 width=68) (actual time=80.060..80.060 rows=1 loops=422)                    |
                            Recheck Cond: (oid = m.roleid)                                                                                                                |
                            Heap Blocks: exact=422                                                                                                                        |
                            Buffers: shared hit=6633590                                                                                                                   |
                            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on pg_authid_oid_index  (cost=0.00..92.40 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=4.491..4.491 rows=15673 loops=422)               |
                                  Index Cond: (oid = m.roleid)                                                                                                            |
                                  Buffers: shared hit=19793                                                                                                               |
Planning Time: 0.833 ms                                                                                                                                                   |
Execution Time: 38471.566 ms                                                                                                                                              |
```

[image]

Comment: The question has been updated. Please let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Whatever else may be going on, it looks like pg_authid and pg_auth_members are in desperate need of being vacuumed.  Unfortunately, I don't know how to make that happen on RDS.  Surely it should happen automatically and you should report that to AWS.